# Resolving transport issues using Twilio API for SMS through VPN with C#

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

I have looked at 2-3 previous posts concerning failed send-SMS-messages in c# using twilio, and one mentioned a possible failure due to 'transport issues'. I may be having this problem, as I'm working through a VPN tunnel and not able to successfully send SMS. The code is really simple, and has been posted before:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        var msg = client.SendMessage("+14", "+18", "TEST");
        if (msg.RestException != null)
        {
            string t = msg.RestException.Message;
        }
    }
```

The **msg** var returns null with no errors/exceptions after the call to client.SendMessage() (so the test for a RestException throws an exception).

I have the identical code running on a 'clean' machine with a direct internet connection. The failure is happening through a business VPN tunnel.

What transport issues can I tell the security team to resolve to get this to work? What ports/protocols are involved with the SendMessage() call?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio is an HTTP based API, so The protocol that `SendMessage` uses is HTTP over port 443 (HTTPS).

If you are getting a null response from the method, I'd suggest breaking out an HTTP debugging proxy tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to watch the HTTP requests made by your application and see more specifically what is is going on with them.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks - I will take it to the security team to get resolved.  Not too confident about that actually, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything more I can do to help!